# laravel очереди

Tags: php, laravel

Вопрос, как в Laravel не дублировать очередь? 
Т.е. Есть определённая работа, которая добавляется в очередь, но как её не дублировать, если она уже стоит в очереди? 
В документации ответа не найдено...

Comment: Очереди находятся в таблицу jobs. Можете попробовать проверять их на наличие там.

Comment: Зачем изобретать велосипед если, возможно, есть решение более простое и лаконичное

Comment: На данный момент решил проблему - дал имя каждой работе в очереди и сравниваю есть ли такая или нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С этим может помочь модуль mbm-rafal/laravel-single-dispatch

Установка:

```
$ composer require mbm-rafal/laravel-single-dispatch
$ composer update
```

Создаем файл миграции:

```
$ php artisan vendor:publish --provider="MBM\Bus\BusServiceProvider" --force
```

запускаем миграцию

```
$ php artisan migrate
```

config/app.php

```
'providers'=> [
    \MBM\Bus\BusServiceProvider::class,
    ...
]
```

Добавляем в
app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
{
    Queue::after(function (JobProcessed $event) {
        app(\MBM\Bus\Dispatcher::class)->unregister($event->job);
    });

    Queue::failing(function (JobFailed $event) {
        app(\MBM\Bus\Dispatcher::class)->unregister($event->job);
    });
    ...
}
```

Источник:
https://github.com/mbm-rafal/laravel-single-dispatch

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/288572)

Comment: @Dmitry, вы безусловно правы, но это ссылка на расширение к Laravel. Пожалуй там и будет храниться самая актуальная информация =)

Comment: Руслан. Модераторы могут преобразовывать тривиальные ответы в комментарии, но будет всё-таки более полезно, если вы наберёте поскорее 50 баллов репутации на ответах и получите возможность оставлять комментарии. Новичков на сайт приходит довольно много, а модераторов у нас мало, просьба понять ситуацию. Для удаления комментария три человека должны просмотреть и проголосовать для удаления, добавил свой голос к голосу Дмитрия.

Comment: @AK я вас понял) Исправил

Comment: Прекрасно, ловите плюс. Установка - это правда ещё не всё, хорошо было бы пример использования добавить.

Comment: @AK спасибо за плюс =) достаточно добавить в AppServiceProvider указанный код в ответе, и все будет работать (как я понял из инструкции)